# why is there a user named "reboot" on my dd-wrt installation?

Tags: router, dd-wrt

I just noticed there is an entry named "reboot" in /etc/passwd

```
root@millie5:~# cat /etc/passwd 
root:_somenoncestring_:0:0:Root User,,,:/tmp/root:/bin/sh
reboot:_somenoncestring_:0:0:Root User,,,:/tmp/root:/sbin/reboot
root@millie5:~#
```

I don't remember creating this user, but maybe its part of dd-wrt installation?
Or maybe I've been hacked. Is this a legit account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you telnet to your router (eg `telnet 192.168.1.1`) you get the login then password prompt. Using a login of `root` and your password takes you to the command line interface while entering `reboot` as your login name and your usual (root) password will run the reboot command and reboot your router.

At the CLI, using the command `setpasswd my_new_password` will change the salted password string on both lines of you `/etc/passwd` file. So, this will change what your password is when both telnetting and on the web interface (where the user*name* remains 'admin').  It doesn't seem possible to have these as different passwords (although could be done with a start up script easily enough).

In short, no, don't think you've been hacked!

You can use it as a quick reboot method if you're testing something or could do some scripting which uses this.